# figures pop up during code is running in matlab

Tags: matlab, figure

I'm running a large code so I would like to ensure everything is correct when it starts to run. One thing I do is to plot some data to see if they make sense. I had several such plots (figure (1), figure (2) ...) and all of them are buried in different 'if' sentences. But I found only some of them pop up during the code is running, the others just don't show up until the code finished running. I have checked all the if statements are true.

Since my code is a little large I can't put it here. Can someone tell me the possible reasons that affect when figures pop up (during the code is running or after it's finished)? Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you use like plot, imshowpair, scatter and other thing like that. The rendering is long and sometime it just pause and display at the end. that can happen but not always.

Comment: you may have a look at `drawnow` -> [doc](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/drawnow.html)

Comment: put `pause(0.000001)` after each plot or imshow and then check

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`drawnow`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/drawnow.html) function to update your figures while code is still running.  If you want your figure window to "pop up" at any given time, you may also need to explicitly call [`figure(figNum)`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure.html).

Note that while it can be fun to watch your figures update in real time, you may incur a severe performance penalty by doing so.  If you have long-running loops, you might consider only showing every N-th update, where N is 10, 100, 1000, or some other appropriate value:

```
for iter = 1:1e6
    plot(x,y);
    if ~mod(f0,1000); drawnow; end
end
```

If you are just interested in plotting right at the beginning as a sanity check, you might run the first iteration of your code outside of a for loop, and run `drawnow` to make sure it plots.  Then enter into the for loop starting at the second iteration.  The advantage over testing `iter==1` is that you don't have to waste cycles on a conditional at every iteration.